# MS Access .Net Add-In - how to install / call on dependent template files

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, deployment, add-in

I am looking for advice on deploying my first .Net add in.

The add in is simply a ribbon button that is active when a certain MS Access application is loaded. The button takes info from a loaded form and creates an email based on the form's control values.

To accomplish this, I use

- A MS Word template (existing resource)
- An XML data dump (created dynamically)
- An XSLT transformation file (existing resource)

I would like the add in to install these resources locally on the client, and reference them when needed.

So how can I get these template files deployed as part of my project into a directory of my choosing?

Comment: Any reason why you don’t just include the custom ribbon in the USYSRibbons table? Why bother with some .net add-in and create world poverty and suffering to just create some custom ribbon?

Comment: Well this is my first non VBA attempt at extending Office Suite functionality. It is for a compiled .mde that I cannot alter, and it has to show up as a Command Bar in certain contexts.  Also how do you plug in code that must execute into an XML only ribbon? What is wrong with creating an Add In?

Comment: Did not think add-ins allowed context menus especially if mde. You can however add ribbon + code as you are attempting via a add-in. As to specify code from the ribbon do you mean VBA code or your .net add-in code? If the ribbon is added to Access ribbon table, then OnAction of the ribbon xml can be set to any public VBA function and will be called when clicked on. If the ribbon is the result of a add-in, then OnAction will call your .net code in your add in code. Since you cannot add VBA code then you only can and would care about the ribbon calling your .net code anyway, would you not?